# Flutter- GestureDetector detect the direction of Horizontal and Vertical Drag

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using `GestureDetector` and didn't find any `onXYZ` event which tells you the direction of drag.

Comment: As Answered by @CopsOnRoad - onPanUpdate  - A pointer that is in contact with the screen and is moving in the vertical or horizontal direction. 
This callback causes a crash if onHorizontalDragUpdate or onVerticalDragUpdate is set.

Comment: @anmol.majhail Thanks for pointing that out, let me update my answer.

Comment: @anmol.majhail I noticed that when I use both `onPanUpdate()` along with `onHorizontalDragUpdate()` there is no crash, however initially the later receives update, after some time, the former callback starts updating and later stops. Can you tell me where did you find we shouldn't use both the callbacks simulatenously?

Comment: It's in Documentation - https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures#gestures

Answer (score 34):

Did you try `onPanUpdate(details)` method? Here is how you can do it.

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onPanUpdate: (details) {
    if (details.delta.dx > 0)
      print("Dragging in +X direction");
    else
      print("Dragging in -X direction");
    
    if (details.delta.dy > 0)
      print("Dragging in +Y direction");
    else
      print("Dragging in -Y direction");
  },
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
    width: double.infinity,
    height: double.infinity,
  ),
)
```

Note: This callback causes a crash if `onHorizontalDragUpdate()` or `onVerticalDragUpdate()` is also provided as mentioned by anmol.majhail.

Comment: onPanUpdate doesn't work.. I added a print line, and it executes it only once.. do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

For those, who have "*Having both a pan gesture recognizer and a scale gesture recognizer is redundant; scale is a superset of pan*." error:

Implementing both drag and zoom-in with [onScaleUpdate] in [GestureDetector] widget:

```
onScaleUpdate: (scaleInfo) {
  //for drag, use [scaleInfo.focalPointDelta.dx] and [scaleInfo.focalPointDelta.dy]
  _controller.translate(scaleInfo.focalPointDelta.dx, scaleInfo.focalPointDelta.dy);
  
  //for zooming use [scaleInfo.scale] and don't react when zoom is exactly '1' [scaleInfo.scale != 1]
  if (scaleInfo.scale > 0.5 && scaleInfo.scale < 2 && scaleInfo.scale != 1) {
    setState(() {
      currentSize = Size(widget.size.width * scaleInfo.scale, widget.size.height * scaleInfo.scale);
    });
  }
},
```