# Flutter change value using GestureDetector, swipe to right or left

Tags: flutter

in flutter application i simple variable as `currentValue` and this variable value should be between `0.0` and `1`, by gesture and swipe to right or left i want to change this value of `currentValue`

swipe to right should be add and swipe to left should be minus, considering latest value of variable, that means, for example:

```
swipe to right => 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 ...


swipe to left  => 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1 ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> {
  double value ;
  @override
  void initState() {
    value = 0.0;
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Text('value = $value')),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate:(DragUpdateDetails details){
                  if(details.delta.dx>0){
                    print('right swipe');
                    //right scroll
                    //increment counter
                    setState(() {
                      value+=0.1;
                    });
                  }
                  else if(details.delta.dx<0){
                    print('left swipe');
                    //left scroll
                    //decrement counter
                    setState(() {
                      value-=0.1;
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54238847/9142279

Comment: and how can i calculate dx and convert it to double?

Comment: why do you want to do that? you said swipe left = -0.1 and swipe right = +0.1

Comment: i want to change variable value by swiping left or right by considering between 0.0 and 1

Comment: i don't know how can i calculate and convert dx to what i want to have